# Find the gamma decay multipole order of 40Ca

Tags: nuclear-physics

The spin-parity of 40Ca is 0+. So the first excited from the shell model is 1f(7/2) state. The gamma decay 7/2 --> 0+ is not possible. So what is the answer here?

I was thinking that the first excited state is of 2 nucleon excitement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the shell model by looking at the number of protons separate from the number of neutrons. The 1st excited state occures when a proton or neutron is excited to its respective 1st excited state. So determine that by applying the shell model to the 20 neutrons or protons. Hence f(7/2) is a much higher state.

Also nuclear decays are a probablistic process. A forbidden decay is really just a decay with a small probability of occuring.